Power Automate flows only run in one machine
I have two machines (user1-pc\user1, user2-pc\user2) that both downloaded power automate desktop and login with same ms account (ex: user1@example.com). They are in same group.
But the flows only run on user1-pc, I get the error WindowsIdentityIncorrect if I turn off user1-pc.

I found this page (Troubleshoot desktop flow...) and use the command dsregcmd /status to check Device State section and found out both machine are not joined. (But flows in user1-pc can be triggered and run normally from cloud flows.)

Then I tried this page to joined my machines but find out they were already joined to my work network.
How can I trigger desktop flows on user2-pc from cloud flows?
